# Building standalone Qt Linux executable

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, compilation, static-linking

I'm trying to build my Ubuntu Qt project as a standalone executable so it can be easily distributed to other Ubuntu users. I found the following guide:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html

However, I can't even get the first step to work. After navigating to the Qt directory, I can't find the configure script (`bash: ./configure: no such file or directory`), and when I search all subfolders, all I can find is something called configure.prf. I attempted to run that script using sudo, but I get the following error:

> sudo: ./configure.prf: command not found

I also attempted to download the Qt installer executable, but it doesn't have any option to install static libraries.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or point me to a better resource.

Comment: Are you trying to install Qt itself or build your program?

Comment: You are trying to find source code in installed Qt package? You should download source code instead. For example, the latest is http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.9/5.9.1/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.9.1.tar.xz , or look it in archive: https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/ .

Comment: Qt is installed, I'm just trying to build my program. The guide says the first step is to install the static Qt libs, which I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: Static libraries should be built from source code, just download it and follow the instruction.

Comment: If you are going to distribute your application to other users of ubuntu you would recommend creating a .deb, and placing Qt packages within the requirements. When downloading Qt from the site on the internet, or through apt-get you are downloading dynamically. The solution you want can be tedious in addition that you have to place some flags in order to activate certain modules that you may want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The [Qt for Linux/X11 - Deployment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html) page does NOT tell you to install a static build of Qt.

What it does is giving you 2 options for distributing your application on Linux systems. One option is using a static Qt build, the other is to use shared libraries. And as static builds of Qt are not distributed, it tells you to build it yourself.

Knwing that you have now 2 choices. The first is to choose between static and dynamic linking. The advantages and disadvantages of both ar extensively detailed on the web. A quick sum up:

- Static lib:

  - No dependancies
  - You have to build your own Qt, the exe file will be larger
- Dynamic lib:

  - You can use Qt as-is. The exe file will be smaller.
  - You have to make sure dependencies will be there at run time.

The second choice is how will you convey your app. The best way would be to create a .deb package. It is quite hard to do, but it will take advantages of the package manager and take care of the dependencies for you (really interesting if you used dynamic linking). Or you could just put the binary in a tarball (zip, tgz, etc.) and give instructions to the end-user about the install procedure (like what package to install).